# check if std::cin operator>> has read the whole line

Tags: c++, input, end-of-line

I'm implementing a little command line parser. Let's say I have a command that requires 2 parameters. I want to let the user type all 3 strings (the command and 2 parameters) on one line, as well as on several lines. Currently I'm having something like this:

```
std::string command;
std::cin >> command;
std::cout << command << " entered\n";
std::string param1;
std::cin >> param1;
std::cout << param1 << " entered\n";
std::string param2;
std::cin >> param2;
std::cout << param2 << " entered\n";
```

Now I want to be able to detect that the user has just entered the command without any parameter, and output directions for that. I think after getting the command I should test if the line contains anything else and if it doesn't, ask the user to type more. I have tried with `eof()` and `fail()` but they do not work. How can I check for that then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read a line, then you should use `std::getline`. Once you have the whole line, you can break it up into words, however many there are.

Comment: well but I think I'm so close to it that I won't have to break the string and count the tokens

Comment: @phunehehe: As out have said you are implementing a command _line_ parser. Reading line by line (e.g. with `getline`) is the only sane way to achieve this. You can do word parsing with `>>` and an `istringstream` from the read line the same way as you are from `cin` at the moment.

Comment: in fact are you sure you really want to write a parser yourself? there are tools that can do it for you, potentially with less effort depending on the language you want to parse

Comment: @Charles: that way seems to be more work: (1) get the line, (2) put it into a string stream, (3) get the tokens and check if it is `""`, (4) ask user to input more if it is. With my original approach, if it works, I only have to (1) check if there are more parameters coming and (2) if there are no more, spit out a string like `"Enter parameter 1: "`

Comment: @jk: thanks for the suggestion but this is part of a school assignment :)